# What is ASL server in the comment of asl.h

Tags: debugging, logging, asl

I am trying to understand how asl.h works, while I am reading asl.h 
According to 
http://www.opensource.apple.com/source/Libc/Libc-583/include/asl.h
comment of this method.

```
aslclient asl_open(const char *ident, const char *facility, uint32_t opts);
```

It is said "Initialize a connection to the ASL server."
I am wondering what is ASL server in this case.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The first place to look for details on using ASL is the manpage, which you can pull up in Terminal using the command:

```
man 3 asl
```

Beyond that, Peter Hosey's *Idle Time* website has [a number of posts detailing how ASL works](http://boredzo.org/blog/archives/category/programming/apple-system-logger).

For people wishing to use ASL from a Swift-based API, there's [the CleanroomASL open-source project](https://github.com/emaloney/CleanroomASL), which also has more details about differences between how ASL works on iOS devices and the Mac.